# Android AWS Amplify.Auth.signUp() / AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signUp() have same errorCodes for error cases

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

How to distinguish error cases for signUp process?

Only one case (password's length is less then 6) is different to others (both for Amplify and AWSMobileClient solutions):

- user password less then 6 symbols:

> {**InvalidParameterException**@11448} "com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 6 (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; **Error Code: InvalidParameterException**; Request ID: 1f65fd14-0d11-483a-9fc2-1dfc9854127e)"

- user password satisfy above demand, but does't not contain uppercase characters:

> {**InvalidPasswordException**@11481} "com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidPasswordException: Password did not conform with policy: Password must have uppercase characters (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; **Error Code: InvalidPasswordException**; Request ID: 2d046ca6-d462-4165-bf27-5575ce806b22)"

- user password satisfy above two demands, but does't not contain numeric characters:

> {**InvalidPasswordException**@11525} "com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidPasswordException: Password did not conform with policy: Password must have numeric characters (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; **Error Code: InvalidPasswordException**; Request ID: b657ff9e-520a-429a-982f-29c1695ca1bd)"

the same errorCode for case when password doesn't contain special symbols like !@#$% etc.

But for Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp() / AWSMobileClient.getInstance().confirmSignUp()  I have different errorCodes:

```
val errorMessage = when (exAws.errorCode) {
    "AliasExistsException" -> 
        mess = 'An account with the email already exists.'

    "CodeMismatchException" ->
        mess = 'Invalid verification code provided, please try again.'

    .  .  .  .  .   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently Amplify Auth and AWSMobileClient use errorCode of exactly the same name but different types. For Amplify Auth, the error type is `Amplify.AuthException`.
Could you please specify your question with more details?

Comment: The main purpose of my question: how to distinguish between the second and third case in my example list (same error code) programmatically? For example, I want to show the user custom messages (or a case of multi-language) and do not use AWS-messages like "Password must have uppercase characters"). And why error code is String? not digit?

Comment: We return the same type currently for those. So now you can't distinguish those two cases.